# Unable to change the publicPath in Vue 3 with Vite.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to change the public path for production build but can't seem to get it to work. When I build for production, I would like to change the public path from `/` to `./` but I could not find anything in the documentation how to do this. I am using **vite.js** as my build tool. Maybe this is something Vue 3 and Vite specific, I'm not sure.

I have tried adding a `vue.config.js` file and also `.env` variables but so far nothing is working.

When I build, I get this output with path starting with `/`:

```
<head>
  <script src="/assets/index.30c61b3b.js"></script>
  <link href="/assets/vendor.29497e16.js">
  <link href="/assets/index.7123a98f.css">
</head>
```

But for **production** I would like it to change to `./` like this:

```
<head>
  <script src="./assets/index.30c61b3b.js"></script>
  <link href="./assets/vendor.29497e16.js">
  <link href="./assets/index.7123a98f.css">
</head>
```

I tried adding `vue.config.js` but it is not helping:

```
module.exports  = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV  ===  'production'  ?  './'  :  '/'
}
```

and also `.env`

```
NODE_ENV=production
BASE_URL=./
```

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer, I needed to add a `base` option to `vite.config.js` like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue({
            reactivityTransform: true
        })
    ],

    base: './',
})
```

https://vitejs.dev/config/#base