# vue 3 + electron: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuejs3

I'm build a vue project to the `dist` folder.
In file `dist/index.html` I see:

```
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-45e10fce.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-c05fc592.css">
```

When I run `npm run electron:start` I see an error
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`
And
`window.location.href = file:///home/alex/logseq-PersonalNetwork/vue-personalNetwork/dist/index.html`

How to fix assets addressing in a vue 3 + electron project?

Answer (score 0):

It helped me add the line `base: './'` to the `vite.config.ts`

see: [Unable to change the publicPath in Vue 3 with Vite.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936407/unable-to-change-the-publicpath-in-vue-3-with-vite-js)